# Element loses properties after class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I was wondering, why changing an element's class (haven't tried with id), makes it not responsive to functions that work with the class set?

Example

js function

```
function addImg(element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
        var $block = $(this).is('img') ? $(this).parent() : $(this);
        var $name  = $block.attr('id');
        $('input[name="'+$name+'"]').click();
        $('input[name="'+$name+'"]').change(function() {
            $block.css('border-color', '#cecece')
            readURL(this, $block);
        });
    });
}
```

DOM

```
<div class="has-img">
   <a class="remove-image"> Remove Image </a>
   <img src="blalbalba.jpg" />
</div>
```

js code

```
$('.remove-image').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('has-img').addClass('no-img').find('img').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});

addImg('.has-img img, .no-img');
```

After `.removeClass('has-img').addClass('no-img')` the `addImg('.has-img img, .no-img');` function doesn't work anymore for that element. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binding only works on elements that have one of those classes at the time the event is bound. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.has-img img, .no-img', function() {
    var $block = $(this).is('img') ? $(this).parent() : $(this);
    var $name  = $block.attr('id');
    $('input[name="'+$name+'"]').click();
    $('input[name="'+$name+'"]').change(function() {
        $block.css('border-color', '#cecece')
        readURL(this, $block);
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-image', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('has-img').addClass('no-img').find('img').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: woho... great tip, using `$(document)`